# Entity framework Migrate with specific DbMigration instances

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, plugins

I'm building a modular implementation of the entity framework (5), and I'm trying to implement modular migrations.

The idea is that each module can register its migrations which are instances of DbMigration (what EF already uses to register migrations).
I intend to use this concept to migrate databases on `Application_Start` and on `Modules_Loaded`

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourMigrationsConfig>());
Database.Initialize(false);
```

Is there a way I can pass all the DbMigrations registered by modules to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`?

---

### Research

I initially thought I would have to subclass MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion however after looking through the source I can't see a point for extensibility but all it does is

```
_config = new TMigrationsConfiguration
     {
          TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionStringName)
     };
```

And then

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(_config);
migrator.Update();
```

so i had a look at the source for DbMigrator, there is a method in there i can override called `GetPendingMigrations` that returns `_historyRepository.GetPendingMigrations(_migrationAssembly.MigrationIds)`

So then I had a look at the `public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetPendingMigrations(IEnumerable<string> localMigrations)` method in `HistoryRepository` class, it's job is to figure out what migrations have already taken place (`databaseMigrations`) and returns the difference between `localMigrations` and `databaseMigrations` => `localMigrations.Except(databaseMigrations);`

So I am able to pass in my own set of Id's there, that allows me to create a set of custom pending migrations.

However there is still a problem; `DbMigrator`'s `internal override void Upgrade(IEnumerable<string> pendingMigrations, string targetMigrationId, stringlastMigrationId)` uses an instance of `MigrationAssembly` class defined in EF.

```
foreach (var pendingMigration in pendingMigrations)
        {
            var migration = _migrationAssembly.GetMigration(pendingMigration);
```

And here is `GetMigration(string migrationId)`:

```
public virtual DbMigration GetMigration(string migrationId)
    {
        DebugCheck.NotEmpty(migrationId);

        var migration
            = (DbMigration)_migrations
                               .SingleOrDefault(m => string.Equals(m.Id, migrationId, StringComparison.Ordinal));

        if (migration != null)
        {
            migration.Reset();
        }

        return migration;
    }
```

THATS PERFECT, i should just override that class... oh wait:

```
internal class MigrationAssembly
```

It's internal also. So how the hell can i override those properties?

Here is a link to the source http://entityframework.codeplex.com

**Update**
I couldn't figure out a way to do this without editing the source. Now I'm looking creating a custom migration architecture using the `DbModelBuilder` class

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations

Comment: Almost. I couldn't tell if Multi-tenancy allows you to foreign key models across contexts. I'm assuming its possible. Do you know?